# Vimwiki: Setting up mathjax

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

I'm trying to set up MathJax to work with vimwiki. According to the manual:

> 1. using the MathJax server for rendering (needs an internet connection). Add to your HTML template the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Which I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>%title%</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=%encoding%">
</head>
<body>
    %content%
</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't work. MathJax equations don't render on my browser, they show up like this:

```
\(\frac {1} {1 + \alpha} \)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vimwiki uses "$" and "$" as a delimiter not "\(" and "\)".

also include this in your  tag, so that MathJax doesn't prompt an error.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.MathJax     =   {
        tex:    {
            inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
        },
        svg:    {
            fontCache:  'global'
        }
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the line you've placed there is not the line mentioned in the docs for vimwiki. Try to put this verbatim:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script> 
  
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

That should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as the template worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>%title%</title>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script> 
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    %content%
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).